# Графический интерфейс в C++ и построение графиков

Tags: c++

> Тело летит под углом к горизонту, надо нарисовать график и сделать графический интерфейс, чем можно воспользоваться: книги, видеоуроки и т.д., желательно ссылками.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь про Windows, то GUI делается в Visual C++ стандартно на MFC. Основы по работе - здесь: [приступая к работе с Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualc/ee340952.aspx). Пример рисования на форме с помощью GDI+: [Scribble Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716527.aspx) (на английском).

Если нужно рисовать мощные графики, то лучше подключить внешнюю библиотеку: от простой gnuplot до maplotlib.